# UITextField not triggering action event upon UIDatePicker action event

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have a datePicker that updates my textField. Once the textField data changes is supposed to perform actions(such as verifying data). The problem is that after the datePicker updates the textField, the textField does not perform any actions, regardless of what action event I am using on the textField, such as .ValueChanged.I cannot figure out what the problem is. I noticed though, that if I am to type something in the textField, the action event works. 
Here's my code:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var customDelegate : CustomTextFieldDelegate?

    enum type {
        case standard
        case date
    }

    var textFieldType : type = .standard {
        didSet{
            switch self.textFieldType {
            case .standard:
                break
            case .date:
                let datePicker = UIDatePicker.MMMddyyyy
                self.inputView = datePicker
                datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshOnDatePicker(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
                self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkFieldInput), for: .applicationReserved)
                break
            }
        }
    }


    @objc private func checkFieldInput(sender: CustomTextField){
        guard let fieldInput = self.text else { return }
        switch sender.textFieldType {
            case .standard:
                break
            case .date:
                customDelegate?.isTextFieldVerified = !fieldInput.isEmpty
            break
        }
    }

    @objc private func refreshOnDatePicker(_ selector: UIDatePicker){
        self.text = selector.date.formattedMMMMddyyyy
    }
}


fileprivate extension UIDatePicker {
    class var MMMddyyyy : UIDatePicker {
        let currentDate: NSDate = NSDate()



    let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!
    calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")! as TimeZone

    let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    components.calendar = calendar as Calendar
    components.year = -100

    let minDate: NSDate = calendar.date(byAdding: components as DateComponents, to: currentDate as Date, options: NSCalendar.Options(rawValue: 0))! as NSDate

    let dp = UIDatePicker()
    dp.datePickerMode = .date
    dp.minimumDate = minDate as Date
    dp.maximumDate = currentDate as Date
    dp.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    return dp
   }
}

fileprivate extension Date {
    /// date formatted type "MMMM dd, yyyy"
    var formattedMMMMddyyyy: String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
        return  formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is a textField, with a datePicker keyboard. Upon picking a date, the textField needs to update and validate the entry. Could be validating the entry with the database

Comment: alright so then I added self.checkFieldInput(sender:self) and deleted self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkFieldInput), for: .editingChanged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 @objc private func refreshOnDatePicker(_ selector: UIDatePicker){
    self.text = selector.date.formattedMMMMddyyyy
    self.checkFieldInput(sender:self)
}
```

Comment: ya, so .ValueChanged or ".anything" does not work. indeed "self.checkFieldInput(sender:self)" works. However I feel like this is rather a hack isn't it? I mean it works, but how come .ValueChanged does not work? I just don't get it. How should I structure it properly?

Comment: valueChanged works and when it triggered it calls refreshOnDatePicker that will set a new text to the textfeild and call the method that validates it's content

Comment: Nothing wrong with this approach it's not a 'hack' in any way.  A UITextField doesn't generate to the .valueChanged events so you can't use that.  In fact a lot of events for UITextField are only fired when the text is changed via the keyboard (virtual or hardware) and not when setting the .text property directly.  If you really want to do something when .text is changed then look into overriding the .text property and using the didSet property observer.

Comment: valueChanged event is associated with the picker not the textFeild

Comment: @ UpholderOfTruth I like how you add a touch to posts , I think we meet alot here in stackOverflow

Comment: is there a way I can make an UIKeyboardType extension to display a date picker? then I can just say self.keyboardType = .datePicker